# Is Array's count property an optional?

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

I created a type alias:

```
typealias areasOfStudyType = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
```

Then a created an optional variable:

```
var areasOfStudy : areasOfStudyType? = nil
```

I need to use the number of elements of the array to put them in a table view so I typed:

```
areasOfAStudy?.count
```

I understand that if `areasOfStudy` is `nil` this line of code won't try to get the value of count because I'm using optional chaining. But when it's not `nil` it will return an `Int`.

However, the compiler complains that I haven't unwrap an optional and suggests that I type:

```
(areasOfAStudy?.count)!
```

Why is `areasOfAStudy?.count` an optional? When I look at the Array's reference documentation I read:

> **count**
> The number of elements the Array stores.
>
> Declaration
> var count: Int { get }

Comment: Optional chaining returns an optional...

Comment: Great! You pointed to the right issue. The Swift Programming language book reads:

Comment: “To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a nil value, the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional value, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying returns a nonoptional value”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3).” iBooks. https://itun.es/ca/jEUH0.l

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count is not optional but the array is.  Therefore areasOfAStudy?.count is optional, because when areasOfAStudy is a nil count never gets called so it evalutes to nil.

```
var areasOfAStudy: [String]? = nil
//This evaluates to nil because areasOfAStudy is nil. The type of a is Int?
var a = areasOfAStudy?.count
print(type(of:a))
```

Comment: This answers my question too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just how optional chaining works.

If you have `let value = nonOptional.property`, assuming `property` and `nonOptional` is not optional, then `value` will not be an optional.

However, if you do `let value = optionalObject?.property` even though `property` is not defined as an optional, you accessed it through optional chaining (that's what the `?.` means) so because `optionalObject` is optional, then `value` is optional as well because `optionalObject` could be `nil`.